# Evaluate F-score with Cross-Validation for multi-class multi-output (multi-target) dataset

Tags: cross-validation

I have a  multi-class multi-output (multi-target) dataset and would want to get the performance value of a model by F-score with Cross-Validation. It seems that function 'cross_val_score()' would work on multi-label data (binary class, multi-output) but not multi-target data ( I got the error here, "ValueError: multiclass-multioutput is not supported"). Please help identify if there is any way to get the results as required. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: @pierpy # First 4 columns of the data are set as x and the rest are y

`x = MTR_data.iloc[:, 0:4]`,

`y = MTR_data.iloc[:,4:]`,

`MTC_model = MultiOutputClassifier(RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=30,random_state=0))`,

`cv = RepeatedKFold(n_splits = 10, n_repeats = 1, random_state = 1)`,

`F_score = cross_val_score(MTC_model, x, y, scoring="f1", cv = cv)`

This code turned out the error as mentioned.